# Hiding labels with value 0 in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, expression

I have a map with a lot of labels with the value 0. I want to hide or remove them somehow and came up with the following rulebased label:

```
if( floor("area") = 0, " ",floor("area")||'m²')
```

Unfortunately, now every label is hidden. But I don't see the error, it should work shouldn't it.

Perhaps the idea with the if question is not good.

Comment: Please explain what you try to do with `floor("area")`. What should this syntax achieve?

Comment: Try to change `" "` into `' '`. Double quote indicates that the string represents the field name, but a single quote represents a raw string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes. Try `''` instead of `""`.

E.g. `if( floor("area") = 0, '',floor("area")||'m²')`

Double quotes `"` refer to fields. In your case to the field " " (whitepsace), which most likely does not exist.

Single quotes `'` refer to strings. If you want it to be just empty, there is no need to add a whitespace.

---

Another suggestion / alternative:

Use a filter for your label instead of a labeling rule which adds empty labels. So your "label with" field contains `floor("area") || ' m²'` and your "filter" `floor("area") is not 0`. This method has the advantage of handling colliding labels better.